# NumPy compare array with negative number

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have this code below:

```
voltsPhasenew = np.array(voltsPhase,dtype=np.float32)
currentPhasenew = np.array(currentPhase,dtype=np.float32)

def ImpP():

    Im = np.subtract(voltsPhasenew, currentPhasenew)

    for I in Im:


        if (np.any((Im)<-90)):

            ImpPhase = 360 + (Im)

        else: 

            ImpPhase = Im 

    return ImpPhase
```

when i run it only the if statement is working the else is doing nothing. How i can compare each element of the Im array with -90 ( a negative number) and then if the element is smaller than the -90 do sth else do sth else? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Shouldn't that be : `np.any(Im<-90)`? Those extra parentheses might be the trouble-makers.

Comment: What is the shape of `voltsPhasenew` and `currentPhasenew`? Also, fix your indentation

Comment: How i can find the shape of those two arrays?

Comment: @Divakar It doesn't make any difference. Just checked

Comment: @quamrana Do you have any idea?

Comment: What is the use of `I` in the for loop?

Comment: @AndreySobolev the shapes are (15,) and (15,)

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but the normal thing one would want a function with these elements to do is to put all of the phases in a specific range, like (-90, 270), or (0, 360), etc.  Is that what you want?  If so, your function is fairly far from that.  The main logical inconsistency is that it 1) loops over the entire array, but 2) within that loop it inspects the entire array (rather than a single element as one would normally do in a loop) ie, for every loop the `if` statement is going to evaluate to the same value, irrespective of `I`.

Comment: @tom10 what i want is to check every element of Im array. If is smaller than -90 do sth else do sth else. Not what u suggest. Basically to compare an np array with a negative number. i thought that np.any() is checking every element of the array.

Comment: Yes, it's checking every element of the array, but it's a constant within your loop.  Maybe just rewrite your code to pull it out of the loop a a constant, and you'll see more clearly what's going on.  Your confusion is what you're looping over and what your not.  Currently you're just doing exactly the same thing N times, and then returning the last time.  It makes no sense.  For example, remove the loop (and just leave the interior for a single pass) and you'll see you get exactly the same output.

Comment: @tom10 Can you be more specific? Show me some code maybe ? ty